# HTML divs not floating right using free marker

Tags: html, css, freemarker

I'm struggling to push a div which contains a table out of the right side of page - opposite the left div. At the moment the second div sits below the first one.

```html
#details { background-color: lightblue; } #summary { background-color: red; }

<div id="details" style="float:left; display:inline">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td><b>Details</b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Details Text:</td>
    </tr>

  </table>
</div>
<div id="summary" style="float:left; clear:left; display:inline">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td><b>Summary</b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Summary Text</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: You want the divs to be next to each other, or?

Comment: I was hoping to get them to be next to each other then using margin left - push the right side over on the right side of the page...

Comment: it seems like @saucedApples has the answer you want.

Comment: Thanks. @MG2016 there are many ways to do what you want and the simplest is in my answer below.

Comment: What does this have to do with [tag:freemarker]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want them to sit opposite, you'd want to float the first to the left and the second to the right. Also, in your example, using `clear: left` is what's pushing the second table down to the second line. I also added style tags to your CSS declaration at the top; otherwise that'll just get placed on the page as live text.

One more note about floats - in most cases there's no need to combine `float` and `display: inline`

```html
<style>#details { background-color: lightblue; } #summary { background-color: red; }</style>

<div id="details" style="float:left; display:block">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td><b>Details</b>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Details Text:</td>
    </tr>

  </table>
</div>
<div id="summary" style="float:right; display:block">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td><b>Summary</b>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Summary Text</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but it's still showing one below the other. I tried both suggestions from above...

Comment: Is it possible that you have some other CSS involved that's setting the width of those `div`s or the `table`s inside them? Maybe set `#details, #summary { max-width: 50% }`

Comment: OK, I'm getting somewhere now. I don't see my text appear within the two divs...?             <style type="text/css">
   #details {
                background-color: lightblue;
    width:50%;
               height:100px;
            }

            #summary {
               background-color: red;
    width:50%;
               height:100px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
     <div id="details" style="float:left; display:inline">
          <span>test</span>
      </div>
  <div id="summary" style="float:left; display:inline">>
      <span>test</span>
      </div>
    </body>

Comment: If I drop that into a fiddle, it shows up just fine. Are you sure there's no extra CSS being applied somewhere? Also, I'd suggest changing those both to `display: block` or just removing the `display: inline` setting altogether

Comment: I just ran it in fiddle and it's just what i need but I don't see why it won't work within pdf markup. There's no further css. The only other bit in my template is: <?xml version="1.0" ?>
<!DOCTYPE pdf PUBLIC "-//big.faceless.org//report" "report-1.1.dtd">
<pdf> - so I'm stuck! Grr. It SHOULD show my text but doesn't.

Comment: Only other thing that I can see is that extra closing tag. I just dropped this into an empty HTML file and it renders as expected ` <?xml version="1.0" ?> <!DOCTYPE pdf PUBLIC "-//big.faceless.org//report" "report-1.1.dtd"> <pdf><head><style type="text/css"> #details { background-color: lightblue; width:50%; height:100px; } #summary { background-color: red; width:50%; height:100px; } </style> </head> <body> <div id="details" style="float:left; display:inline"> <span>test</span> </div> <div id="summary" style="float:left; display:inline"> <span>test</span> </div> </body> </pdf>`

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

You simply need to change `style="float:left;"` to `style="float:right;"` and remove the `clear` & `inline-block`'s from both `div`'s,

```html
<div id="details" style="float:left; background-color:lightblue;">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td><b>Details</b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Details Text:</td>
    </tr>

  </table>
</div>
<div id="summary" style="float:right; background-color:red;">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td><b>Summary</b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Summary Text</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```